# displaying image using alexa custom skill set

Tags: node.js, esp32

I am new to alexa skillset. My intention is to display the image taken from ESp32 CAM module in the alexa Echo show device.
When i send the URL to the ESP32 it will take a photo and send the image.
I can able to view the image by using the mentioned URL in the web browser.
I tried it in skill set development console->Test tab, I am getting "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" error.
Here is my code to display the image:

```
const PhotoShowIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
&& Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'PhotoShowIntent';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
//const speakOutput = 'Hello World!';
const speakOutput = 'Working on it.. photo will appear soon';
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
.speak(speakOutput)
.addDirective({
type: 'Alexa.Presentation.APL.RenderDocument',
token: 'helloWorldToken',
document: {
type: 'APL',
version: '1.4',
mainTemplate: {
items: [
{
type: 'Image',
source: 'http://192.168.11.11/capture'
}
]
}
}
})

//.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
.getResponse();
}
};
```

Does anyone have idea on this?